# What is a ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I've found the following definition [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) but it's still not clear to me:

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value

Do you have any examples?

Comment: What code threw the error?

Comment: `int("hello")` - it got a string, which is OK, but the *content* of the string doesn't represent an integer. Note this website is basically a repository of examples of people hitting errors, so https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+valueerror should find you plenty.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`math#sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt) - it takes a number, but this number must be non-negative. If you try calling it with a negative number (which can't be done in real numbers' math), you'll get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Answer (score 1):

An example that gives the specific `ValueError` is this:

```
import 
math.log(0)
```

which gives back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-f7278b7c2ed1>", line 1, in <module>
    math.log(0)

ValueError: math domain error
```

Many other math function will produce the same when given bad inputs (`math.sqrt(-1)`, `math.ceil(math.nan)` and so on...)